# How Set.contains() decides whether it's a subset or not?

Tags: java, iterator, set, subset, hashset

I expect the following code would give me a subset and a complementary set.

But actually, the result shows that "Error: This is not a subset!"

What it.next() get and how to revise my code to get the result I want?
Thanks!

```
package Chapter8;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class Three {
    int n;
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Three three = new Three(10);
        three.display(three.set);
        Set<Integer> test = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Iterator<Integer> it = three.set.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            test.add(it.next());
            three.display(test);
            three.display(three.complementarySet(test));
        }

    }

    boolean contains(Set<Integer> s) {
        if (this.set.contains(s))
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }

    Set<Integer> complementarySet(Set<Integer> s) {
        if(this.set.contains(s)){
            Set<Integer> result = this.set;
            result.removeAll(s);
            return result;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error: This is not a subset!");
            return null;
        }
    }

    Three() {
        this.n = 3;
        this.randomSet();
    }

    Three(int n) {
        this.n = n;
        this.randomSet();
    }

    void randomSet() {
        while(set.size() < n) {
            set.add((int)(Math.random()*10));
        }
    }

    void display(Set<Integer> s) {
        System.out.println("The set is " + s.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to know Set api before using Set. Please cover my tutorial [Internal life of HashSet](http://volodial.blogspot.com/2013/07/internal-life-of-hashset-in-java.html)

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi Your link is broken, is the article still available elsewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is in this part:

```
set.contains(s)
```

that doesn't do what you think it does, it doesn't take as an argument another `Set` to see if its members are contained in the first`set`. It rather looks if the argument passed it is in the Set.

You need to iterate over the "contained" set and use `set.contains(element)` for each element in the contained set.

Answer (score 46):

You probably want to use `set.containsAll(Collection <?> C)` for checking if Collection(Set, in this case) is a subset of 'set'. From the docs: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

> boolean containsAll(Collection c)
>
> Returns true if this set contains all of the elements of the specified
>   collection. If the specified collection is also a set, this method
>   returns true if it is a subset of this set.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you'd like to use java streams, you can:

```
set.stream().allMatch(element -> set.contains(element)); // untested
```

Comment: This would always return true. What you mean is `setB.stream().allMatch(element -> setA.contains(element))` or  `setB.stream().allMatch(setA::contains)`. Then again you could just do `setA.containsAll(setB)`